# Set up Heroku and GoDaddy?

Tags: heroku, dns

I am trying to get a domain name I bought through GoDaddy to work with my Heroku hosted site.

How do I configure my domain name to work with Heroku?

Comment: I don't agree that the question is too broad. I find it quite specific. Setting up a ruby on rails app with heroku and create a GoDaddy domain that points to it. I had the exact same problem and the answer here provided gave me the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 302, accepted):

**[Updated 31.10.2014]** Allright! It works! Here is how I did it from scratch, so others with the same problem can fix it too. First I will explain how to setup Heroku and GoDaddy, then I will explain how to create a naked domain (www.example.com -> example.com).

**Setup Heroku and GoDaddy:**

1. In your project folder in terminal (on your computer) write `heroku domains:add www.example.com` (where `www.example.com` is the domain you have bought at GoDaddy)
2. Sign in to GoDaddy -> DOMAINS -> choose your domain ->
   Launch (this will take you to the Domain Details)
3. Click 'DNS Zone File' tab
4. Remove the CNAME record named 'www' (which points to @)
5. Click 'Add record' -> CNAME(Alias) -> 'Host' should be `www` and
   'Points to' should be your Heroku address (example
   `supermoo-bil-3411.herokuapp.com`). TTL can be 1 hour.

It can take some time for the DNS to propogate. For me it took about 10 minutes.

That's it! `supermoo-bil-3411.herokuapp.com` will now be under `www.example.com` :)

**Create a naked domain:**

A naked domain removes the need to write www in front of your domain name. This can be done by  forwarding `example.com` to `www.example.com`. This is super easy on GoDaddy:

1. In the same window as above, click on the 'Settings' tab
2. Under Forwarding -> Domain -> Click 'Manage' -> then click 'Add Forwarding'
3. 'Forward to' should be `www.example.com` (your domain), 'Redirect type' should be '301
   (Permanent)', 'Forward settings' should be 'Forward only'
4. Make sure "Update my nameservers and DNS settings to support this change. (Recommended)" is checked

   That's it! You are done :)

**Useful links:**

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Thanks to Ryan Kazinec for help :)

Comment: When I try adding the domain (heroku domains:add www.example.com) I get:  No account specified.Run this command with --account <account name> Do you know what is this account?

Comment: What should the cname record become if you install an ssl cert via herokus addons?

Comment: I think it is important to note that if you remove ALL records, as you suggest in step 4, that if you have email, google apps, or other services set up, you can really mess things up. The only records that need to be edited to make this work are the A record and the CNAME records for www and any subdomains included.

Comment: @allegutta did you implement SSL on your site. If so, does the alias just point to the herokussl url?

Comment: @Moosa Hi, I haven't done that yet. If you do, let me know how you solved it.

Comment: It's just CNAME not CNAME(Alias)

Comment: @jackblank So in the GoDaddy setup, it only stands CNAME now?

Comment: i was missing removing default cname with www

Comment: This answer is great! - make sure on terminal run `host www.example.com`

Comment: I've done all this, but I don't know how to change the 'DNS Target', which was provided by my Heroku CLI: `*domain*.com.herokudns.com` - I tried inputting this into the NS (Nameservers) section, but I guess this is not right... (the one where it has two servers, `ns17.domaincontrol.com` and `ns18.domaincontrol.com`).

Comment: One of my CNAME records looks like this
CNAME www @ 1 Hour
I am trying to add another one as you mentioned
CNAME www www.zup.chat.herokudns.com and it keeps throwing this error
The specified CNAME already exists in the zone. any ideas

Comment: @PirateApp you can edit the already existing CNAME record and instead of @ you can write 'www.zup.chat.herokudns.com'. You don't need to add a new one.

Comment: I just followed this and it took less than 60 seconds to work.... super quick

Comment: Superb! Same speedy results as loxyboi

Comment: I have tried but it is not working for naked domain

Comment: this did not work for me.... https://myapp.com does not solve properly, it just show an error... the rest of the http are good to go

Answer (score 1):

DNS settings tend to have a lag time.

Have you attempted to access the app from another device? (Say a smart phone that is operating on another network?) I've seen on several occasions where my local dns cache was causing issues which is why accessing it from another device may shine some light on your situation.

If you're making the dns changes from a windows based pc you can flush your dns cache which can sometimes resolve your issue.

1.) Right Click on CMD.exe (aka command prompt)
2.) Click on Run as Administrator.
3.) type: ipconfig /flushdns
4.) Press Enter key

But bear in mind dns changes can take a while to propagate.

Comment: Hi, it has been three days since I did the DNS setup, and I have tried to load the site on different devices and machines. How long does it usually take?

Comment: There's a field called TTL in your DNS record. This tells other DNS servers how long (in seconds) to cache a DNS entry. Set this to a low value while you're testing and then crank it up once you have your DNS figured out. Some DNS servers may override the TTL with their own value, so beware, but I think at worst this is usually a couple of hours.

Comment: Usually a couple of hours at most but I've seen warnings that it can take up to 24 hours to propagate. Nonetheless three days should be plenty of time.

Comment: Here is a more detailed tutorial compared to the one you mentioned in your question: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I did all the steps in this tutorial too :) It should work but, it doesn't.. Do I need to change the `A(Host)` IP adress at GoDaddy, or is `CNAME(Alias)` the only thing I should change?

Comment: No problem. Okay, I found the following screen casts that may shed some light on this. After watching the first video (without email support) it was mentioned that first all of the cname records need to be removed first, then you add the two additional entries. Before you do this I would save a screen shot of all of the entries you currently have so they can be restored if something goes wrong. Also, these videos are a few years old. I don't use heroku so I can't confirm they're still accurate.  http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/10/7/heroku_casts_setting_up_custom_domains/

Comment: Thanks for the link Ryan, it really helped me solve this!

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://dnsimple.com/r/ecc41c23013629 and open an account.

They have a one click set up for heroku and you can set the TTL to as low as one minute.
Then on the GoDaddy side just change the dns servers from the go daddy servers to the dnsimple ones(all explained on the dnsimple site).   SIMPLE ;)

Your domain is still hosted by GoDaddy

GoDaddy is not the place to be managing you dns in my humble opinion.

Comment: I made it in GoDaddy. But Ill check it out! Thanks :)

Comment: No reason to pay for DNS when Godaddy's work fine for basic use cases.

Comment: Very basic use cases.
There is always the free version of cloudflare if ya don't want to pay for a decent dns service ;)

Comment: Cloudflare makes site slow.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to setup an external domain with Heroku is using this addon: https://addons.heroku.com/zerigo_dns - You simply have to point the dns nameservers to

```
a.ns.zerigo.net
b.ns.zerigo.net
c.ns.zerigo.net
d.ns.zerigo.net
e.ns.zerigo.net
```

I am not affiliated with Zerigo DNS - just a happy user. Any yeah it's free for 50,000 queries per month and for $20/month you get unlimited queries.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As of January 31, 2014 Zerigo will no longer offer the free account

Comment: Oh dayum. Might put my DNS on cloudflare instead.

Comment: I can see free account now