# GoDaddy tells me my Heroku app doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125175/setup-heroku-and-godaddy) to deploy an app with Heroku on a GoDaddy domain.

But when I check my url, I get the following error message:

```
Heroku | No such app
There is no app configured at that hostname.
Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL.
```

Under my GoDaddy "Edit Zone Record" page, I have Host => "www", Points To => "(heroku app name)", and TTL => "1 hour"

When I copy and paste the contents of the Points To field into the url bar, it brings up my live site with no errors.

So why would it be telling me there is no such app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the domain name to your Heroku app?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: Yes, I ran `heroku domains:add (custom url)`.

Comment: Did you add it for the correct app and did you add both the bare domain and the subdomain (www)?  You can check by running `heroku domains`

Comment: Ah, the problem was that I ran that command before I set up GoDaddy. Running it again solved my problem.