# Error Switching from AWS to Heroku?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku

I have a static website (HTML) hosted on AWS. I just closed my account and I'm hosting it on Heroku. So it's running fine now using the url domainname.heroku.com
but when I try to use my custom domain name www.domainname.com
it doesn't work. I get:

403 Forbidden

Code: AllAccessDisabled

Message: All access to this object has been disabled

RequestId: F42E2D54503B0028

HostId: PdeViOEs3DIZw4HhtSfR7ZZJfW+ykO7FvKa48

Is this problem coming from AWS or Heroku? Plzz help!

Comment: Where is your authoritative DNS for your custom domain, is it AWS Route 53? Also, what is the target for the www.domainname.com CNAME record?

Comment: I'm with godaddy. I just followed the instructions in here and waiting for effects to take on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125175/setup-heroku-and-godaddy

Comment: dns target: domainname.herokuapp.com

Comment: It's working now. Just had to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have done the following then you may just need to clear your local dns cache or wait for dns to propagate as that error is from AWS, so your browser is still resolving to the old environment.

In your project folder in terminal (on your computer) write heroku domains:add www.example.com (where www.example.com is the domain you have bought at GoDaddy)