# Add GoDaddy naked domain to Heroku app

Tags: url, heroku, dns, ip, shared-hosting

#### Heroku [custom domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

*I've setup **two** custom domains for my Heroku app.*

```
example.com        example.com.herokudns.com
*.example.com      wildcard.example.com.herokudns.com
```

---

#### Domain configuration

*I configured my domain as follows:*

1. I added a `CNAME` Record for `*` pointing to `wildcard.example.com.herokudns.com`.
   **Works fine.**
2. I forwarded my `URL` using GoDaddy's Domain Forwarding tool, because I can only specify `IP` addresses as `A` records.

---

#### Problem

The domain forwarding points to `example.com.herokudns.com`. Unfortunately GoDaddy automatically prepends `http://`, so it actually does not open my app and instead shows a Heroku message:

> There's nothing here, yet.

---

#### Goal

Setting up my GoDaddy root domain to point to my Heroku app.

---

**Note:** GoDaddy automatically added an `A` record for `@` pointing to `>>++FWD1++<<`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### [Cloudflare](https://cloudflare.com) does the job!

*Finally, I achieved my goal of using my **naked** domain as host by choosing CloudFlare to handle my DNS configuration.*

Resources:

- [CloudFlare allows `CNAME` Records to be the naked domain](https://blog.cloudflare.com/zone-apex-naked-domain-root-domain-cname-supp/)
- [How `CNAME Flattening` works](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root)

---

**Note:** CloudFlare has a pretty good documentation and setup process, you just need to:

1. add your domain to CloudFlare
2. follow the CloudFlare setup guide

   - updating your nameservers *(in my case GoDaddy)* to point to CloudFlare

Comment: make sure that you have Heroku set to receive ssl on it's dashboard, then on CloudFlare set the sll to **full** instead of _flexible_

Answer (score 2):

What did you set your DNS to forward to? I had this same problem, but solved this creating a Heroku DNS entry for *www.myapp.com*. Heroku creates a DNS target of *www.myapp.com.herokudns.com*.

**Here is my setup:**

- DNS forwarding to www.myapp.com
- DNS CName of www to www.myapp.com.herokudns.com
- Heroku DNS added www.myapp.com

Comment: Tell me if I am wrong, but that way I have to use the subdomain `www` and that's what I try to circumvent :-)

Comment: This still has the problem that `https://myapp` doesn't redirect correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by setting up a nginx server with docker in five minutes.

First follow the instruction on this link: https://pentacent.medium.com/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71

Then add your nginx server ip to your `A Record` with host name `@`

In you nginx server you can use this code to redirect all traffic to your `naked` domain to `www` domain. Just replace all `your-domain.com` with your domain.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name your-domain.com;

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/certbot;
  }

  location / {
      return 301 https://www.your-domain.com;
  }
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name your-domain.com;

  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/your-domain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/your-domain.com/privkey.pem;


  location / {
      return 301 https://www.your-domain.com$request_uri;
  }

}
```

Answer (score -4):

In [Setup Heroku and GoDaddy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125175/setup-heroku-and-godaddy) *allegutta* solves the issue by masking the heroku-app-name domain with the .com domain. Instead of `slooob.com.herokudns.com`, use your original heroku app url (`[heroku-app].herokuapp.com`) and it should work. Just worked for me.

Comment: For me that does show the url `[heroku-app].herokuapp.com` in the browser address bar, if I redirect to `http://[heroku-app].herokuapp.com`. Is it possible to use `slooob.com`?

Comment: You mean when you enter sloob.com the user is redirected to the real app url? That shouldn't happen.

Comment: I mean the redirection shouldn't happen. Is it still like that? If so, can you post a picture of your CNAME records?

Comment: Ah, yea the point was that I want to prevent redirecting from `slooob.com` to `www.slooob.com`. I achieved this at the end by using CloudFlare's Alias Record.