# Godaddy dns configuration not working with Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, cname, domain-name

After I read many articles and Stackoverflows,
I set at

---- Godaddy ----

```
CNAME host      => www
      points to => example.herokuapp.com
Forwarding      => http://www.example.com
```

---- Heroku ----

```
Domain names
 example.com
 www.example.com
```

THEN when I curl

`curl -v -H "Host: www.example.com" www.example.com.herokudns.com`

it returns the HTML I want properly.

However, when I go to `www.example.com` or `example.com` on the browser,
Heroku says

```
"There's nothing here, yet."
```

Why?

Comment: have you added the domain at heroku's end.?

Comment: I did 
```heroku domains:add myappname.com & heroku domains:add www.myappname.com ```
in the console and domains and DNS targests are set to

```myappname.com.herokudns.com &
www.myappname.com.herokudns.com```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. There are 3 things I want to note.

1. It could take more than 2 days for the connection between Godaddy and Heroku to be valid.
2. The settings I did was correct.
3. I suggest using Cloudflare, which I learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41535263/9956279) (Make sure to access your website using `https` after implementing Cloudflare) because this method seems to be a robust solution.

   - Note that it is not clear whether No.1 or No.3 solved the problem.

Thank you for all the help and comments :).