# Heroku and Godaddy don't want working together

Tags: heroku, dns

I have an app on heroku.com, code-w.herokuapp.com (works fine).  I have a domain, that I bought: gamakers.org.  I have done all that described in [Setup Heroku and GoDaddy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125175/setup-heroku-and-godaddy)

I have got no result.  When I open gamakers.com, it says,

> This website is temporarily unavailable, please try again later.

Meanwhile, I can see my favicon is loaded.

Next when I open www.gamakers.com, it says

> Bad Request (400).

P.S: I discussed the problem on GoDaddy with their support, they said: If Heroku can't give you static IP of the site, we can't help you. But documentation on heroku.com says, we DO not use static IP for our apps, we use only URL. So, I took my url from Heroku CLI and put it on Godaddy. No results. Please, who has heroku + GoDaddy site working fine right now, help me. Thanks.

Comment: Might I suggest you ask this question on http://serverfault.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: More question is more on topic with serverfault or superuser, as it has nothing to do with programming. See Heroku documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#dns_setup   You need a CNAME or some sort of ALIAS. Also you have choices in the domain name registrar and DNS hosting solutions, if one provider is not delivering you the services you need, why not changing for another one?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Sorry for bothering you, then I will ask on severfault.com. I just didn't know about this service! And If nothing helps, I really  will change the provider.